# Threading.Timer updated value not reflected in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, timer

I am using VS express 2010 and .Net 4.0.

I bind a DataGridView to a BindingList which implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

The value changed is reflected on the grid normally but failed when using Threading.Timers to do the update job.

As shown below , the value is updated but not shown unless the cells lost focus like "minimizing and maximizing" or "the grid is covered by other window" or "selecting the cells".

http://i.minus.com/jViIpKKeNNRrB.PNG

I am a newbie. I had searched and I believe the threading.timer is bad in updating UI. But in my case, I am just updating the value.

I am tired of playing with the weak threading.timer. Any other recommendations for light-weighted timer would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Threading.Timer` isn't "bad" at updating the UI, it just fires its event on a different thread to the UI thread and since UI must be updated on the UI thread you're having your difficulties.

You need to `Invoke` the update back on the UI thread.

The easiest way to do this is:

```
myControl.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    myControl.Text = "Hello";
}));
```

Obviously replace your code into my example.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I don't know much about invoke so I read and tried. I invoke a method in my form (UI thread?) containing the grid to call datagridview.Refresh(). It works. Should the update be done in this way using refresh? Is it a bad practice?

Comment: @TaiMingChan - You only use `Invoke` if you are calling from a thread other than the UI thread. It is required in that circumstance. If you're on the UI thread then there's no need to call `Invoke`.

Comment: I read more and understand the concept now. Thank you for your help! Anyway, I guess there might be a better solution than grid.Refresh() to fix the "updated but not shown" problem as the Grid.Refresh() is bad with more and more data.